# add reset to css without interfering old files

Tags: css, sass

I just inherited a CSS/SCSS project that doesn't use any CSS reset or normalize.

My project structure is something like this:

```
- config/
- utils/
- blog/
- style.scss (imports everything)
```

Basically I want to add a `reset.scss` files somewhere and create new pages by using that reset.

My problem is how can I add a reset to my CSS without interfering with the older .scss files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only by IF statement somewhere in `<head>` and `<link>` on server side or create two different `index.html` (for example) files with own `<link>`s to stylesheets. Solve this problem only by CSS is impossible, you can't use global styles like normalize.scss for local needs.

Comment: thanks, but finally I decided to encapsulate the reset inside a class (.is-clean) and each new page use this class.